# MySQL - Ignore certain rows depending on different conditions

Tags: mysql

As an example I have a `Pokemon` column with certain data inside, many of them repeat

Pokemon

```
Wartotle
Pichu
Pikachu
Pichu
Kadabra
Charmelon
Squirtle
Wartotle
Wartotle
Pidgeotto
Pidgeotto
Diglett
```

What I need is to ignore certain data, if a specific data on the same `column` doesn't exists. Specific data from the `pokemon` column must exists before I fetch data via `SELECT`

What I want is something is a query that do something like this but on multiple data

```
SELECT * FROM table 
(
    If `Pichu` doesn't exists then don't `SELECT` `Pikachu`
    If `Abra` doesn't exists then don't `SELECT` `Kadabra`
    If `Squirtle` doesn't exists then don't `SELECT` `Wartotle`
    If `Pidgety` doesn't exists then don't `SELECT` `Pidgeotto`
    If `Squirtle` doesn't exists then don't `SELECT` `Wartotle`
    If `Charmander` doesn't exists then don't `SELECT` `Charmeleon`
)
```

So the final result of the `SELECT` query I need would result in something in this

```
Wartotle
Pichu
Pikachu
Pichu
Squirtle
Wartotle
Wartotle
Diglett
```

I know it's a bit confusing request but it's the query I'm looking for

Comment: I think it's imposible to do that using only one query. Stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first find those that you do not want to include (subquery) and exclude those from the result (outer query):

```
select t.name
from table1 t
where t.name not in (
  select s.skip
  from (
    select 'Pichu' as search, 'Pikachu' as 'skip'
    union
    select 'Abra', 'Kadabra'
    union
    select 'Squirtle', 'Wartotle'
    union
    select 'Pidgety', 'Pidgeotto'
    union
    select 'Squirtle', 'Wartotle'
    union
    select 'Charmander', 'Charmeleon'
  ) as s 
    left join table1 t1 on t1.name=s.search
  where t1.name is null
);
```

Btw, based on your rules, the `Charmelon` should be included in the result set.

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=984a168a9fccd1ff98026caaafcd0981)